# Get the date and time from string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the date and time from String in xslt.

Input:

```
<xml>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>MKTDATQ - NZX Market Data. Prepared at 2019-06-27 17:30:25</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</xml>
```

Output should be:

```
<root>
  <date>5:30pm Thursday, June 27, 2019</date>
</root>
```

I have no idea how can I process the date and time in XSLT. Please help me to solve this. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `xslt` template to get the `date format` you wanted. `xpath` is enough

```
//xml/table/tr/td/format-dateTime(
        xs:dateTime(concat(substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 18, 10)
        ,'T'
        , substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 7,  string-length(text()))))
    , '[h1]:[m01][P], [MNn] [D], [Y]')
```

Answer (score 1):

For easier comprehensibility, I divided the process in two steps:

1. Create a [`xs:dateTime`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) from the string (Here the context node is assumed to be `td`).

   > The ·lexical space· of dateTime consists of finite-length sequences of characters of the form: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`

   In this case a `T` has to be added between the date and the time.

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="dateVar" select="xs:dateTime(concat(substring-before(substring-after(.,'Prepared at '),' '),'T',substring-after(substring-after(.,'Prepared at '),' ')))" />
   ```
2. Format this variable with `for-dateTime()` [(Some examples for formatting strings)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples)

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dateVar,'[h]:[m01][Pn] [FNn], [MNn] [D1] [Y]')" />
   ```

The output with Saxon is

> 5:30p.m. Thursday, June 27 2019

The `p.m.` seems to be XSLT processor dependent. I don't know of a way to make it a `pm` (in the examples it is `pm`).